# How to take multiple pictures before dismissing camera picker

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I want to be able to present the camera picker, and take multiple pictures before dismissing the modal view. I would also like to display how many pictures the user has taken before the view is dismissed. Is this possible? I'm aware that I would have to use an overlay for the image count, but I don't know how to take multiple pictures before dismissing it. I can't seem to find any information on it. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/) is one that says it can. Take a look.

Comment: I am actually using that, but it doesn't work for the camera. It only allows me to select multiple images from the photo album, and not the camera. Thanks though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PhotoPicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) is a sample project provided by Apple which does exactly what you are talking 
about. It even allows you to make your own custom `OverlayViewController` to display the extra features. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at **`takePicture`** method of [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) which programatically initiates still image capture.

You can initiate additional captures after receiving `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate callback.

Hope it helps.